# Windows, restoring window bug

Tags: windows, winapi, rendering, restore

I'm playing around with Windows and D2D1
However when restoring my minimized borderless/menuless window
sometimes I get this very ugly bug

[image]

For a frame (or a few more) before the window gets drawn with D2D1
it will display this title bar with the name of the window.
This happens on about 5-10% of the restore operations.

The window class style is set to

```
CS_DBLCLKS|CS_OWNDC
```

but Ive also tried other styles.

The Window is created with `CreateWindow` and `WS_POPUP|WS_SYSMENU` as `dwStyle`

My rendering method is called on `WM_PAINT` but I also tried to move it so it
gets called every time but that does not help.

Any help is appreciated :)

#

I've found a workaround which I'm not completely fine with
Instead of calling `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE)`
I call

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

This however results in the taskbar icon being "renewed" which I dont want either.

Short simplified example code which features this problem (when minimizing/restoring)

```
#include <Windows.h> 

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPSTR cmd, int cmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX TestWC = { 0 };
    TestWC.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    TestWC.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50, 50, 50));
    TestWC.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    TestWC.lpszClassName = "Testklasse";
    TestWC.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_OWNDC;
    TestWC.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    RegisterClassEx(&TestWC);

    HWND htest = CreateWindow("Testklasse", "Test", WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE, 200, 200, 400, 248, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    MSG wMsg = { 0 };
    bool shown = true;
    while (wMsg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&wMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&wMsg);
            DispatchMessage(&wMsg);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT) & 0x8000 && shown)
        {
            shown = false;
            ShowWindow(htest, SW_MINIMIZE);
            continue;
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DELETE) & 0x8000 && !shown)
        {
            shown = true;
            ShowWindow(htest, SW_RESTORE);
            continue;
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END) & 0x8000)
            PostQuitMessage(1);
        Sleep(50);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: *"My rendering method is called on WM_PAINT but I also tried to move it so it gets called everytime"* - Not sure what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: I thought that the bug might occur because there are other messages handled when restoring before my window gets painted black by my drawing function. However this isnt the case, said bug occurs even when not drawing anything and using the DefWindowProc

Comment: Please show your code. Something else (possibly unrelated to Direct2D, so please show the complete program) might be wrong. And yes, you do want to have your rendering code in `WM_PAINT`, even with Direct2D; check the Direct2D examples.

Comment: done, btw i know about that I was just getting desperate

Comment: Remove the `Sleep` from your message loop. Not only does it limit rendering frequency, but also message handling. That's something you definitely don't want.

Comment: again: it does NOT matter in this example :)

Comment: It **does** matter. If you limit message handling to no faster than one message per 50ms, you are slowing down your application's responsiveness, for no apparent reason. If you need help, post the code you need help with. If you post code that contains `Sleep` in it's message loop, people will continue to ask you to remove it. For good reasons, too.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself:
Minimizing and restoring a borderless window
is undefined behaviour.
A workaround is to catch the WM_NCPAINT and draw the WHOLE
window yourself (even if its borderless it has a non-client area).